# Akka-http - configuration of request and host-level pools

Tags: akka, akka-http

What is the relationship in terms of pool settings between the super-pool used by the Request-level API, and the cached pool created by the host-level API?

To provide more context:  I need to query the same host/endpoint with fast, responsive requests, and with more expensive requests.  My current strategy is to use `Http().singleRequest()` for the cheap queries, and a cached host-pool to "isolate" the more expensive queries.  I want to make sure that the expensive queries won't use up all the connections available in the super-pool.

Am I right in my expectation that they will indeed be 2 separate pools even though they point to the same host?  If so, is there a way to configure, say the max-connection count, for the super pool and for the cached pool separately?  I only see one setting in the `reference.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you don't specify different configurations, Akka-HTTP will cache the underlying pool and share it. This holds for both `Http().singleRequest(...)` and `Http().cachedHostConnectionPool(...)` calls.

If you want different pools, the trick is to provide different configurations, as the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/host-level.html#configuring-a-host-connection-pool) state:

> Note that, if you request pools with different configurations for the
>   same target host you will get independent pools.

Both `singleRequest` and `cachedHostConnectionPool` calls take an optional `settings: ConnectionPoolSettings` parameter. You can create this from the default one and tweak the params you want to tweak, e.g.

```
Http().cachedHostConnectionPool("localhost", 80, ConnectionPoolSettings(system).withMaxConnections(2000))
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Stefano Bonetti say, the easy workaround for this is to force akka-http use different cached pools by configuration, for example if you use singleRequest() api you can change the user-agent and then akka create diferent pools for you, a code example in java can be:

```
 UserAgent userAgent =  UserAgent.create(ProductVersion.create("akka-http", "1.0", actorPath));

    ConnectionPoolSettings setting = ConnectionPoolSettings.create(context().system())
            .withConnectionSettings(ClientConnectionSettings.create(context().system())
            .withUserAgentHeader(Optional.of(userAgent)));


    http.singleRequest(httpRequest, http.defaultClientHttpsContext(), setting, context().system().log(), materializer).... Here code to handle the response
```